# Jest encountered an unexpected token. ReactJS and axios issue

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm building an application with ReactJS and trying to do the tests with Jest. However when running  "npm run test" I get the following error:

> Jest encountered an unexpected token
>
> Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.
>
> Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.
>
> By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

followed by the specific issue:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

```
  1 | import React from 'react';
  2 | import { render, screen, fireEvent, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
> 3 | import axios from 'axios';
    | ^
  4 | import Income from '../src/components/Income';
  5 |
  6 | jest.mock('axios');
```

this is my jest.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
};
```

and my babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-react',
    '@babel/preset-flow',
  ],
  plugins: [
    'babel-plugin-styled-components',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
  ],
};
```

Anyone know how to fix this? Thank you!

I tried forcing this into Jest through the package.json:

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^axios$": "axios/dist/node/axios.cjs"
    }
  }
```